Every SQL ROUND function has a "+ .0049" . . . why?
This isn't a problem per se.  We are just trying to understand the code we've inherited.  While troubleshooting a problem, we noticed that every line that is using a ROUND function contains "+ .0049".
Since the developer is no longer with our organization, I decided to figure this out.  The Google machine did not provide an answer.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Why add the .0049 to this function?
Here are a few examples with some of the names changed to protect the innocent.
Round(a.Delta * (a.Covered_Hours + a.Ratio * IFNULL(b.Leave,0)) +0.0049,2)

ROUND(a.Rate - b.Rate,0) * a.Ratio * IFNULL(b1.Holiday,0) +0.0049,2)

ROUND(Hours * Delta+0.0049,2)


control of rounding because of floating point precision problems. Though I wouldn't say that this would happen much perhaps for your cases the developer had it enough so he forced it through. So for instance, lets say you have a 1.9949 which because floating point precision the real number is something like 1.994899999999999 and in this particular instance you want it to round up, so you force add 0.0049 to it so it becomes 1.999799999999999 which then ROUND will return 2 instead of 1.99

I think whoever wrote this doesn't know about CEILING()

@Barmar beat me to it, I was about to post a second comment with it :D

@Barmar although one difference is that ceiling will round to the nearest integer and wont consider decimal places?

@JorgeCampos Right. The equivalent with CEILING() would be CEILING(Hours * Delta * 100) / 100

@Barmar Which conversely doesn't improve much against the 0049 version :D maybe a user defined function with a proper naming would work better

@JorgeCampos True. I was just trying to rescue after not reading the original code carefully :)

round does banker's rounding, so there isn't any +... that will make it work like ceiling, and since they almost certainly wanted ceiling that means the round is not actually doing what they want

In early version of MySQL, rounding values was incorrect...
As an example :
SELECT round(0.95 * 3.5, 2) => 3.32

But the correct answer is not 3.32 but 3.33 accoring to IEEE standard that  SQL ISO uses...
I suppose that the 0.0049 added was to correct the bug...

no, then they'd be adding .0001 or such; adding this is to get it to round up instead of rounding to nearest.

"the bug" is documented and still exists; mysql will use banker's rounding on most systems for non-exact values.
